# Determine if $x(t)$ is periodic. If periodic calculate its period.

Tags: functions

Determine if $$x(t) = \cos(8t) + 4 \sin(8t)$$ is periodic. If so, calculate its period.

Comment: The first thing I would do is go on wolfram alpha and graph it.

Comment: carlod: Calculate what?  You stopped mid sentence.

Comment: i need to see if this function is periodic, if it is i need to calculate, I don't even know where to start thanks

Comment: @carlod: He means calculate what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find any common period (typically the smallest period) of the individual periods of the sinusoidal terms $\cos(8t)$ and $4\sin(8t)$. A function $f$ is periodic with period $T>0$ if $f(t)=f(t+T)$ for all $t$.

We can write a sinusoidal term as $\cos\left(2\pi\frac{t}{T}\right)$, where T is the period of the sinusoid.

So we can rewrite the first term $\cos(8t) = \left(\cos(2\pi\frac{t}{\frac{\pi}{4}}\right)$. Then $T=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

The second term $4\sin(8t) = 4\sin\left(2\pi\frac{t}{\frac{\pi}{4}}\right)$. Then $T=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

The smallest common period is $T=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: where can i find more information about this, it really help but i would like to read more about since I have one more problem to do

Comment: If you Google periodic function, you should find some good info. Wikipedia might be more formal. I suggest you go to Wolfram Alpha like Jordan said. Also, if you have a textbook for your class, that would be an excellent place to look. I encourage you to first try to understand the material, and then apply it to do your homework. Good luck!

Comment: let me see if I understood, OK I have x(t) = Cos(3t + pi/4) i know it is periodic because it has a positive number, now to solve it, I would cos(t) = cos(3t + T); t = 3t + T so T = 2t but this is not periodic right? –

Comment: I don't think you understand correctly. If x(t) = Cos(3t + pi/4), it's periodic simply because it's a sinusoid. All sinusoids (i.e. cos(w), sin(w), e^(j*w) ) are periodic in the continuous-time domain (not necessarily though in the discrete time domain). You interpreted the formula wrong. Look at it again. And try to understand the whole concept, not just the method for solving your homework problem. Good luck.

Comment: I am very thankful for your help, and you are right about why I need to understand the whole concept, and not just the method, this is my problem that i always have. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

To check if a function is periodic, you need to know that $x(t) = x(t+c)$ for some fixed constant $c$. Let us figure out what $c > 0$ is (if it just so happens to exist). Notice that if $x(t) = x(t+c)$, then
$$
\cos(8t) + 4\sin(8t) = \cos(8(t+c)) + \sin(8(t+c)) = \cos(8t + 8c) + 4\sin(8t+8c).
$$
for all $t$. This is definition of what it means for $x$ to periodic with period $c$. So let's ask ourselves if this can happen and what is the smallest value of $c$ that it does? We know that both sine and cosine are periodic with period $2\pi$. Therefore, since $\cos(8t) = \cos(8t + 8c)$ for all values of $t$, we know that $8t = 8t + 8c - 2\pi$ and so $c = \pi/4$. This value also works for the sine. It is the smallest such $c$ for otherwise sine and cosine would need to have a period less than $2\pi$, which isn't the case. Therefore, $x$ is periodic with period $\pi/4$.

Comment: very helpful, thanks

Comment: let me see if I understood, OK I have x(t) = Cos(3t + pi/4) i know it is periodic because it has a positive number, now to solve it, I would cos(t) = cos(3t + T);  t = 3t + T so T = 2t but this is not periodic right?

Comment: Hi Carlos, not quite. Note that the definition of periodic is $f(t) = f(t+c)$ for some $c$. Therefore, there should also be a 3 in front of your $T$. May I ask why it's 3 now and not 8?

Comment: thanks for responding, there is 3 because this is a different problem that i am trying to solve to see if I understand the all system. x(t) = Cos(3t + pi/4)

Comment: Ohhh, I'm sorry! I misread it. Well, $x(t) = \cos(3t+\pi/4)$ is also periodic. You want $x(t) = x(t+c)$, which translates into $\cos(3t+\pi/4) = \cos(3(t+c)+\pi/4) = \cos(3t + 3c + \pi/4)$. We get $3t +\pi/4 = 3t + 3c + \pi/4 - 2\pi$, which solves to give $c = 2\pi/3$. Anytime you have just a cosine or a sine, it is always periodic.

Answer (score 1):

**Some hints**

1. A function is periodic with period $P$ if $f(t)=f(t+P)$ for all $t$.
2. These trigonometric identities can be used to simplify the expression:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \cos(a+b)&=\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b,\\
   \sin(a+b)&=\sin a\cos b+\sin b\cos a.
   \end{align}
   $$

Comment: thanks I needed a little reminder about trigonometric identities

Answer (score 0):

Let $1=r\cos A,4=r\sin A$ where $r>0$

So, $1^2+4^2=r^2(\cos^2A+\sin^2A)\implies r^2=17\implies r=\sqrt{17}$

$\cos A=\frac1{\sqrt{17}},\sin A= \frac4{\sqrt{17}},\tan A=4$

$\cos8t+4\sin8t=\sqrt{17}(\cos8t\cos A+\sin8t\sin A)=\sqrt{17}\cos(8t-\arctan 4)$

Now, if $f(t)=\sqrt{17}\cos(8t-\arctan 4), f(t+T)=\sqrt{17}\cos(8(t+T)-\arctan 4)$

The period is the minimum positive constant value of $T$ such that $f(t)=f(T+t)$

$$\sqrt{17}\cos(8t-\arctan 4)=\sqrt{17}\cos(8(t+T)-\arctan 4)$$

iff $$\cos(8t-\arctan 4)=\cos(8(t+T)-\arctan 4)$$

iff $$8t-\arctan 4=2n\pi\pm(8(t+T)-\arctan 4)$$ where $n$ is any integer

Taking the '+' sign, $T=-\frac{2n\pi}8=-n\frac\pi4$

As the period is the minimum constant positive number, it will be $\frac\pi4$ putting $n=-1$

Taking the '-' sign, $8t-\arctan 4=2n\pi-(8(t+T)+\arctan 4)\implies T$ is dependent on $t$ hence not constant

Answer (score 0):

The above signal is  periodic.

Simple hint: If $\pi$ is in the denominator, the signal is non-periodic, otherwise the signal is periodic. As an example, consider

$$W=2\pi f_0 \\
f_0=1/T \\
T=2\pi/w$$

so in the above question, the fundamental frequency is $8$, and
the answer is $\pi/4$ which is periodic, and same for the other.